# what is systemtap

Tags: package-management, eclipse, repository

what is systemtap. I downloaded eclipse when I want to build my project it says make sure systemtap is installed I follow this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678283/run-configuration-in-eclipse) It says **sudo apt-get install systemtap** So what is systemtap?

Comment: Read the [SystemTap Beginners Guide](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/systemtap):

> instrumentation system for Linux

There's also a [link](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) to the homepage of the package there, which has more info:

> SystemTap provides free software (GPL) infrastructure to simplify the
>   gathering of information about the running Linux system. This assists
>   diagnosis of a performance or functional problem. SystemTap eliminates
>   the need for the developer to go through the tedious and disruptive
>   instrument, recompile, install, and reboot sequence that may be
>   otherwise required to collect data.